# Vagrantでネットワーク設定を変更するには？

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

[Ruby on Railsの開発環境の構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/TakayaTkmr/items/fe0c8ac03403e2ff00f3)

上記のページを参考にVirtualBoxとVagrantをインストールしてみたのですが、

> confit.vm.networkは内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチファイルとして認識されていません

と出ます。どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

[image: 実際の画面です]

Answer (score 2):

`config.vm.network ...`の部分はコマンドで実行するのではなく、設定ファイルに記述する内容になります。

`vargrant init`を実行した後、コマンドを実行したフォルダに`Vagrantfile`が作成されるようなので、そちらを任意のエディタ等で開いて(参照したページの手順に添って)必要箇所を書き換えてみてください。

参考：
[Vagrantfile - Vagrant by HashiCorp](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/)
[よく使うVagrantfileの設定のまとめ](https://www.virment.com/vagrantfile-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

スクリーンショットを見る限り、あなたがコマンドプロンプトで実行しているのは`config.vm.network` というありもしないコマンドです。それでエラーが出ています。

通常`vagrant init` した後に実行すべきコマンドは `vagrant up` です。

`vagrant up`が実行されると、 cubick さんの言うとおり、Vagrantfile の内容が読み込まれて、その内容に従って vagrant が virtualbox と連携処理を行います。